# Jquery var to php but do not return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a HTML form that I want to send to PHP but also some javascript variables. These JS vars are not in the form. How can I get both to th PHP class?

Below is the code I have so far.

```
$("#login_FORM").submit(function() {        
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('../class/login.Class.php',{
            //.. serialized form data
            screen:screen.width
            //...ser
            //...
            },function(data){
            alert(data);
            window.location.href = "";
        });
    });
```

The `screen` variable ends up perfectly in `login.Class.php` but when it gets to the end of the php file... it returns to above javascript function.

Even when using a `header` into php it returns to the javascript function. It simply reads that page as well and returns everything thats returned in there.
    echo $_POST['hash'];
    header('Location: ../index.php'); die();

Only if I use a `window.location.href = "";` in javascript I can redirect to a correct page after processing the javascript data in the `login.class.php` file (redirecting to correct page isn't the only reason I'm asking the question...fyi)

How can I send variables from jquery / javascript to PHP and continue from there? aka not return to the (success) function the variables were send from.

Comment: Not really clear what you are trying to do. What does *"stay there"* mean? It sounds like you don't want ajax at all and just want to submit form and let server manage output of new page

Comment: I have a HTML form that I want to send to PHP but also some javascript variables. These JS vars are not in the form. How can I get both to th PHP class?

Comment: what exactly are you wanting to happen after submit? That part isn't clear. If you want server to load new page then just add some hidden fields for the other data

Comment: I want the form to be processed and inserted into the database through PHP, but before that I want to have a javascript function alter some of the form input along with some extra JS vars. These can be quite a substantial amount of vars. For which I don't like to have so many hidden fields.

Comment: But that does not answer what should happen after form submits. Be specific! Good idea to read [ask]

Comment: When the form submits all its data should go to a JS function, get processed and from there send to PHP to be continued processed there. Not sure how more I could clarify.

Comment: And stay on same page? That is not clear at all and neither is *"stay there"*. Sending a redirect from server won;t affect browser loading new page

Comment: No, I want to continue in PHP with either a location function or call another class... the question is. How can I send data from javascript to php without returning to the javascript function. With the function in my post I always go back to the alert in the javascript function and have the entire PHP file output alerted. I do not want to go back to javascript, not back to the alert.

Comment: Check below my solution. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Still not sure what you're asking.  The ajax request is sent to your php server and returns immediately.  The success function is invoked when your php page sends a response back.  Everything is under your control: your success function doesn't have to do anything, and you determine when to send response back from php.

Comment: Back to either submit normally or do a javascript redirect in success callback. If redirect with javascript and need that same data that was just submitted will need to store it in session

Comment: I just want the exact functionality as a `<form action='../class/login.Class.php'>` but with the input processed in javascript first. I really dont know how else I can form my question

Comment: In the submit function, you can perform any processing you want before making the ajax call.  Then your ajax call will invoke your php page.  
You can do whatever you want in php (and take as much time as you want to do it) -- the success function won't be invoked until your php page returns.  In your php page, you can call whatever functions you want.  It sounds like you might already know this -- if so, then what is it that we're missing here?

Comment: and what if I want to use a 'Header('Location:');` in php, maybe generate a new page with php. But all it will do is return the html output as a variable back to the Ajax call instead of actually echoing.

Comment: If you want server to redirect you need standard from submit...use hidden fields. If you have a lot of variables turn them into one object instead and serialize that as value for one hidden field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to pass the serialized form data plus some jquery variables if that's the case you could use serializeArray()

```
var data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
data.push({var1: 'value', var2: 'value'});

$.post("myPage.php", data);
```

**EDIT**

I think i got what you are trying to do, if you submit the form using jquery ajax it will always return to the success function because any redirection in php will only redirect the ajax request and not the current "screen".In that case try the following (not a 100% but here it goes):
add hidden fields to your form say:

```
<form action="/class/login.Class.php">
    <!-- form content n stuff -->
    <input id="var1" name="var1" type="hidden" value="someValue" />
    <button id="letsGo" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

$('#letsGo').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    $('#var1').val('dasValue');
    // replace as many hidden inputs as you need
    form.submit();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: After looking deeper into this, it will still take me back to the call. I want the exact functionality as a <form action='../class/login.Class.php'> but with the input processed in javascript first

Comment: @KrijnvanderBurg I think I got what you are tring to do please see my updated answer